# Computation of PDF $f_{Z}(z)$, where $Z=XY^{-1}$ and $X$ and $Y > 0$ are independent [I am primarily seeking a hint]

Tags: probability

The distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are respectively unknown, hence I am trying to derive a (preferably) compact expression of e.g. $f_X$ etc., if possible. Furthermore it is given that $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, as presented in the title.

---

My assertion is as follows,

$F_Z(z)\triangleq \mathbb{P}\text{r}(Z \leq z)=\mathbb{P}\text{r}(XY^{-1}\leq z)$,

thereby I am seeking for an alternative (suitable) formulation of $\mathbb{P}\text{r}(XY^{-1}\leq z)$ and furthermore differentiate to obtain the sought for PDF,

$f_Z(z)=\dfrac{\partial \mathbb{P}\text{r}(Z\leq z)}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial \mathbb{P}\text{r}(XY^{-1}\leq z)}{\partial z}$.

I have also derived $f_{Z \mid Y}(z)=yf_{X}(yz)$, $f_{Y\mid Z}(y)=yf_X(yz)$ and $f_{Z\mid X}(z)=\dfrac{x}{z^2}f_X\left(\dfrac{x}{z}\right)$ etc. if someone perhaps sees an application.

---

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y > 0$, you could equivalently write
$$ \mathbb P(X/Y \le z) = \mathbb P(X \le z Y)$$
If $z < 0$ this is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x) (1 - F_Y(x/z))\; dx $$
while if $z > 0$ it is
$$ F_X(0) + \int_0^\infty F_Y(x/z)\; dx$$

Comment: Bayes theorem states $f_{Z,Y}=f_{Z \mid Y}f_{Y}$ and we know that $f_Z(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{Z,Y}(z,y)dy$, where we make the insertion in the integrand. We further know that $f_{Z \mid Y} = yf_X(yz)$.